# Print to console when method is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to print a message to the browser console or to the page so I can see exactly when each method is called. Nothing is being printed and I haven't found a working solution. I tried using flash messages but it didn't work as well. I'm learning Rails so I want to see exactly what is being called and when. For example if create was called I want to see a message "Create was called!". I have tried this:

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController

  # only index, show, new, and edit pages will have views
  # create, update, and destroy will do some kind of work and then redirect
  # instance variables are visible in our view files
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    # find the post and find the id that was passed into the url
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    flash[:success] = "SHOW WAS CALLED IN FLASH"
    puts "SHOW METHOD WAS CALLED!"

  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      redirect_to(posts_path, :notice => "Your post was saved!")

    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    puts "<p>EDIT METHOD WAS CALLED!</p>"

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
        puts "UPDATE METHOD WAS CALLED!"

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
      redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been saved."
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
     puts "DESTROY METHOD WAS CALLED!"

     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     @post.destroy

     redirect_to(posts_path, :notice => "Post deleted")
  end


end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use logger for this and tail `log/development.log`

```
logger.debug "Method was called"
```

`debug` level logging will only be logged in development environment. use `info` if you want to log in production

Answer (score 0):

Using puts in the controller action won't print it on the web page in the browser. It will be printed in the terminal where your server is running in case you are using Webrick. 
If you want to print it on the webpage, you need to do so in the view corresponding to the action like this:

In **show.html.erb** write:

SHOW METHOD WAS CALLED!

You can log the statements in the log files using Rails.logger in the **action**.

```
Rails.logger.info "SHOW METHOD WAS CALLED!"
```

This will be written to the development.log/production.log file depending on which environment your application is running.