# Print on console (rails s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a new app using Rails 5.

How can I debug using a Rails 5 app.

I mean my purpose is only to write on console when starting **puma** on `development` environments.

I have set

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)
config.log_level = :debug
```

but `logger.debug "app"` in my **controllers** seems not to be useful.

Has anyone try to write on server output with Rails 5 ?

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print to console when method is called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999341/print-to-console-when-method-is-called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried rails 5 yet, but this blogpost looks as if it could help you:

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/12/rails-5-allows-to-send-log-to-stdout-via-environment-variable.html

Comment: This link is broken.